# Can an Archive node rebuild all transactions by syncing with another full node

Tags: archive-node

is is possible that Archive node can rebuild all transactions from genesis by syncing with another full node
scenario

- 5 sealer nodes which are full node [gcmode=full]
- recently i created 1 new node which is an archive node [gcmode=archive] , i will be using,  geth --syncmode full --gcmode archive

when i start this new archive node , will it be able to rebuild all transactions starting from genesis by syncing with another full node ?

Answer (score 0):

Developer advocate from [chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

TLDR, yes it is possible.

In fact, I think a Geth full node can just turn into an Archive node by itself. (not 100% sure about this though).

The main difference here is an archive node keeps the historical state data, and a full node does not. However, a full node still keeps all historical transactions and block information which can be used to generate state data upon request.

> Full nodes only keep historical blockchain data (blocks and transactions) and occasional historical snapshots they can use to regenerate older states on request. They do this by re-executing past transactions in the EVM, which can be computationally demanding when the desired state is far from the nearest snapshot.
> [source](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/archive-nodes/)

We have an article ["EVM nodes: A dive into the full nodes vs. archive nodes"](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/) explaining the differences in detail. It may be helpful for you.

As a developer(not as a Chainstacker), I still recommend you consider using an RPC provider like us. Setting up an archive node is very computationally intensive and may take weeks/months to finish. Keeping the node running is a pain too because of its huge storage space requirement.

Comment: Access to an archive node start from our Growth plan, You can check out the price on this page: https://chainstack.com/pricing/. You will receive 3M free requests every month and additional usage cost 10USD/1M requests. It is def cheaper than setting up an archive node by yourself.